Can noninteracting Bose-Einstein condensate reach infinite density?
If particles are noninteracting, does it mean that the density can be infinite in the ground mode of the Bose-Einstein condensate?
For example, here they are investigating the photon condensate interaction strength. They determine the photon interaction by measuring the change in the condensate size with respect to the photon number in the ground mode. The more photons, the larger the condensate size, leading to repulsive photon-photon interaction.
Let us assume that there are no interactions. It means that one could pump as many photons as they want but the condensate size would not change, leading to a divergence in the photon density. Does that make sense?

The absence of particle interaction does not allow an infinite density for the physically reachable thermodynamic states, and this conclusion is valid for every non-interacting system, classical or quantum.
The relevant concept is that even an ideal non-interacting system has pressure. Depending on the external condition, in a non-interacting system, pressure is a function of some variables describing the thermodynamics state and diverges when density diverges. Therefore a state of infinite density would require an unphysical infinite pressure.

In a finite volume? That would require infinite mass.
At a point? That is the singularity in the center of a black hole. A singularity is predicted general relativity, which is not a quantum theory. At small sizes, like that of a singularity, quantum effects become important. So we need a quantum theory of gravity to predict what happens there.
Most physicists do not believe that the singularity is real. Extreme but finite densities are reached. It is doubtful that what reaches the center of a black hole is still a Bose-Einstein condensate.

A Bose-Einstien condensate forms when Bosons all (or mostly) are in the ground state. This requires two things. Bosons and low temperatures.
Neutrons are Fermions. Pairs of Fermions sometimes form Bosons, but only at low temperatures. Neutron stars are very hot. They are tiny. They have the mass of a star, but the surface area of a city.  It will take far longer than the current age of the universe for them to radiate away significant heat. They are not Bose-Einstein condensates.

Nice answer (+1) Could you elaborate also whether a very high density BEC would be equivalent to a neutron star? The BEC state being reversible suggests that the protons and electrons are not yet merged... if protons and electrons were to merge and become neutrons, it would seem to entail a loss of information / irreversibility of this new neutron star state?

Still, there are convincing analyses predicting BEC formed by Cooper pairs of superfluid neutrons in the crust of neutron stars. See, for instance https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1140/epjd/e2014-50380-3.pdf

It looks like a Neutron star is considerably more complex than my simple picture.
